# Как сделать выборку данных по условию-из файла формата Excel с помощью MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

Необходимо сделать выборку данных по условию. Данные находятся в табличном виде, в файле формата Exсel. Какой вообще должен быть алгоритм решения задачи?

То-есть нужно обратиться к файлу Excel как то?(если да, то как?). Или сначала сделать экспорт потом импорт???(в mysql и обратно).

Основная проблема-непонятен алгоритм решения. SQL начал изучать вчера

Answer (score 2):

1. В Excel сохранить как csv
2. Заимпортить в MySQL
   https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/
3. Написать select с условием.

Comment: Благодарю, пошел пробовать.